# Multiple intents call with single utterance in Actions on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Is there a way to let the user activate multiple intents with a single utterance?

Example:

User: I sat on the sofa and I kicked the ball

I want that "I sat on the sofa" triggers the sitting-intent and "I kicked the ball" triggers the kicking-intent

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in Dialogflow a user utterance will only match a single intent at a time. If you are looking for more advanced logic, you could do additional matching in a webhook or create an intent that would match both inputs in a single phrase.